# Can I use multiple Ads Networks in one Android mobile application?

Tags: android, multiple-columns, ads

**Can I use multiple Ads Networks in one Android mobile application ?**

Comment: have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use multiple Ad networks. However, I would suggest going with Ad Mediation(Google Admob has this) since it will allow you to integrate the various ad networks with just SDK installation rather than installing each for every network.

See this - [Google Admob Mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/)